# Regex to select entire paragraph by matching the reference number from the paragraph

Tags: regex

I am using the following regex to match the paragraph starting with "F61:" followed by the reference number "ABCD1234"

```
(?!F61:).*?(ABCD1234)
```

but this matches only the line containing the reference number, I want to match the entire paragraph containing the reference number.

Here is a sample text

```
F61: Statement Line                                                            
               Value Date:          201203          2020 Dec 03                     
               Entry Date:          1203          Dec 03                            
               DebitCreditMark: Debit/Credit Mark:          C                       
               Funds Code:          D                                               
               Amount:          XXXXXX          XXXXXX                        
               Transaction Type:          X                                         
               Identification Code:          XXX                                    
               Reference for the Account Owner:          XYZ1234 

    F61: Statement Line                                                            
               Value Date:          201203          2020 Dec 03                     
               Entry Date:          1203          Dec 03                            
               DebitCreditMark: Debit/Credit Mark:          C                       
               Funds Code:          D                                               
               Amount:          xxxxxx          xxxxxx                        
               Transaction Type:          X                                         
               Identification Code:          xxx                                    
               Reference for the Account Owner:          ABCD1234
```

The reference number to be matched: ABCD1234

Desired output:

```
F61: Statement Line                                                            
               Value Date:          201203          2020 Dec 03                     
               Entry Date:          1203          Dec 03                            
               DebitCreditMark: Debit/Credit Mark:          C                       
               Funds Code:          D                                               
               Amount:          xxxxxx          xxxxxx                        
               Transaction Type:          X                                         
               Identification Code:          xxx                                    
               Reference for the Account Owner:          ABCD1234
```

Comment: Is [`F61:[\s\S]*?ABCD1234`](https://regex101.com/r/02DyoE/3/) what you want?

Comment: @HaoWu That _won't_ work, because if the first `F61` to be matched does not have that reference number, then your `[\s\S]*` could potentially match across several paragraphs.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know what you mean now, you're right.

Comment: @HaoWu I'm usually wrong though, so I appreciate your comment `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a tempered dot here:

```regex
\bF61(?:(?!F61:).)*?\bABCD1234\b
```

Explanation:

```regex
\bF61          match starting "F61"
(?:(?!F61:).)*?  then match all content WITHOUT passing over another "F61" until the nearest
\bABCD1234\b   "ABCD1234" reference number
```

### Demo

Note that the above demo is running the regex in dot all mode, so that the tempered dot can match across new lines.

Comment: Good solution! Although I think you should use non-capture group `(?:(?!F61:).)` because it's creating so many back references but never used  :p